An elevator is falling, there is air resistance outside, would a person inside fall to the floor?
An elevator is falling, as in the real world, with some air resistance outside slowing the fall.
There is a person inside the elevator. Would the person experience some force pulling them towards the floor? In other words, if the person was in the vertical center of the elevator at the start of the fall, assuming the fall is infinitely long, would they eventually land on the floor?

What do you think, and why?

@Peter, I think yes, the person must fall to the floor eventually, because the elevator would experience the same forces as the person inside, but also the air resistance slowing it down. So relative to the elevator, the person must be falling. However, I am not sure about one thing. Would the person also experience air resistance because there is air inside the elevator (forgot to explicitly mention in the question), or would they be falling together, and the air inside wouldn't slow down the person's fall?

You said, "...air resistance outside slowing the fall..."
Well, how do you slow something that's moving? You push on it. The air slows the falling elevator by pushing up on it. But you're inside the elevator, shielded from the relative wind. What prevents you from falling faster than the elevator? That's easy! The floor of the elevator pushes up on you.
That upward push from the floor of the elevator feels exactly like the upward push that the spectators outside feel from the ground that they are standing on—the push that stops them from falling to the center of the Earth. We call that push, "gravity."
The upward push from the floor of the elevator—the push that stops you from falling faster than the elevator—is indistinguishable from gravity. If the elevator falls long enough to reach its terminal velocity (no longer accelerating downward) then the force you feel inside will be exactly equal to gravity.

Would the person experience some force pulling them towards the floor? - Yes as the downward force on the person due to the gravitational attraction of the Earth stays the same.
What changes is the the upward force on the person due to the floor.
If the elevator starts from rest and the air inside the elevator is not moving relative to the elevator/person then as the elevator increases in speed the upward force due to the elevator will increase from zero so that the acceleration of the person is the same as the acceleration of the elevator.
As time progresses and the speed of the elevator increases then so does the air resistance of the elevator which also means that the force on the person due to the floor of the elevator also increases.
This continues and the speed of the elevator and the person inside the elevators tends to a constant (terminal) speed when the net force on the elevator (and the person) is zero.
